# Azure Data Factory automatically re-trigger failed pipeline

Tags: azure, if-statement, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I want to automatically Re-trigger a failed pipeline using the If Condition Activity (dynamic content).

Process :

- Pipeline 1 running at a schedule time with trigger 1 - works
- If pipeline 1 fails, scheduled trigger 2 will run pipeline 2 - works
- **Pipeline 2 should contain if condition to check if pipeline 1 failed** - This is the Issue
- If pipeline 1 failed, then rerun else ignore - need to fix this

How can this be done?

All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helps you, can you mark it as the answer of this question? :) [Link about how to mark answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you an idea,

For example. Your pipeline1 failed by some reasons. At this time, you can create a file to Azure Storage Blob.

[image]

(Here is an example, you can use the activities what you want to use.)

Then create the trigger2 triggered by a blob been created.

Answer (score 0):

can't you do it with "Execute Pipeline" activity?
For example:

You create a simple pipeline named "Rerun main pipeline" and use "Execute Pipeline"  inside that and link it to "main pipeline". Then in main pipeline, you add failure output and link it to "Rerun main pipeline".